# Simply getting all events in Google Calendar API V3 in Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I've been looking for some simple example code to get a list of events and access their data (Start date, end date and their description). I'm relatively new to java but have been programming in various high-level languages for about ten years now. Regardless, I just can't seem to get my head around what I would have thought to be the most basic requirement for such an API. My failed attempts are below:

```
public class CalenderController {

public CalenderController(String email, String pkey){

    GoogleCredential credentials;
    try {
        credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
          .setJsonFactory(new GsonFactory())
          .setServiceAccountId(email)
          .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"))
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(pkey+"-privatekey.p12"))
        .build();
        Calendar client = new Calendar.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credentials).build();
        Events events = client.events();



    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

  static void display(Events feed) {
        if (feed.getItems() != null) {
          for (Event entry : feed.getItems()) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
            display(entry);
          }
        }
      }
  static void display(Event event) {
        if (event.getStart() != null) {
          System.out.println("Start Time: " + event.getStart());
        }
        if (event.getEnd() != null) {
          System.out.println("End Time: " + event.getEnd());
        }
      }
}
```

and

```
public class CalendarSample {
/**
 * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name
 * is {@code null} or blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested
 * format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
 */
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Michelle Cal Client";

/** Directory to store user credentials. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/calendar_sample");

/**
 * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to
 * make it a single globally shared instance across your application.
 */
private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory
        .getDefaultInstance();

private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;

static final java.util.List<Calendar> addedCalendarsUsingBatch = Lists
        .newArrayList();

/** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            JSON_FACTORY,
            new InputStreamReader(CalendarSample.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret()
                    .startsWith("Enter ")) {
        System.out
                .println("Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=calendar into calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
            .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
            new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}

public CalendarSample() {
    try {
        // initialize the transport
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        // initialize the data store factory
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

        // authorization
        Credential credential = authorize();

        // set up global Calendar instance
        client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

        // get next event
        CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getEvents() throws IOException {
    CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().execute();

    if (feed.getItems() != null) {
      for (CalendarListEntry entry : feed.getItems()) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");    System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getId());
        System.out.println("Summary: " + entry.getSummary());
        if (entry.getDescription() != null) {
          System.out.println("Description: " + entry.getDescription());
        }
      }
    }
}

}
```

Yes, the json file does load and I have got the relevant imports for API v3 but after that I'm stumped.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details about what goes wrong or does not function.

Comment: Well the code presented is incomplete and I can't find documentation to complete it. There are inconsistencies throughout what I can find and plenty oc coverage of the deprecated API system but simply getting a list of all of a user's calendar's events.

Comment: Turns out that the google API explorer answered my question. Due to an addon on my browser it wasn't loading properly but now I know what I need is accessible here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list